# Heretic order/disposition on a 3 columns grid

Tags: sass, susy-compass, susy

I want to make a simple 3 columns / 3 rows grid with Susy 2 like :

```
 1   2   3
 4   5   6
 7   8   9
```

But the blocks are floating in a buggy and heretic order.
You can have a look :
http://img.spheerys.fr/images/2015/01/05/bug-susy.jpg

Here my HTML Markup :

```
<article class="block">1</article>
<article class="block">2</article>
<article class="block">3</article>
<article class="block">4</article>
<article class="block">5</article>
<article class="block">6</article>
<article class="block">7</article>
<article class="block">8</article>
<article class="block">9</article>
```

Here my Susy map :

```
$susy: (
  global-box-sizing: border-box,
  use-custom: (
    rem: true
  ),
  columns: 12,
  column-width: 4em,
  gutters: 1/4
);
```

And finally, my Sass :

```
.block
  +span(4 of 12)
  &:nth-child(3n)
    +last
    +break
```

What's going wrong ?

Comment: I can't recreate the problem with the code you provided (see [my sassmeister attempt](http://sassmeister.com/gist/e8e119d24ae8c4877ec1)). Is there other markup? Other sibling elements? Other CSS that is affecting things?

Comment: You were right : there is some markup just before and when I'm delete it or if I insert two empty <div></div><div></div> before the articles, the float is going well. Very very strange behaviour... I have "solved" it for now with the "<div></div><div></div>" tip...

Answer (score 0):

`:nth-child` counts *all sibling elements*. So `:nth-child(3n)` doesn't just apply to every 3rd `.block`, it applies to every 3rd sibling that is *also* `.block`. The best solution when using `:nth-child` is to wrap all your list items in their own parent, without other siblings.

Susy also provides a shortcut to creating this sort of gallery layout...

html:

```
<!-- wrap all your blocks in a div -->
<div>
  <article class="block">1</article>
  <article class="block">2</article>
  <article class="block">3</article>
  <article class="block">4</article>
  <!-- more blocks... -->
</div>
```

sass:

```
.block
  +gallery(4 of 12)
```

That should be all you need.